# ARDUINO LiquidCrystal does not name a type; did you mean LiquidCrystal_h?

Tags: arduino, lcd

this is my code, it doesn't compile, i don't know what's going on. please help. error: .

code:

```
include "zmienne.h"
include <LiquidCrystal.h>
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2; 
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void logowanie();

void gra();

void logowanieGra();

void setup() { 
pinMode(p1pin,INPUT);
pinMode(p2,INPUT);
pinMode(p3,INPUT);

lcd.begin(20,4);

Serial.begin(9600);

Serial.println("start");

//logowanie

while(login == false){

lcd.setCursor(4,0);
lcd.print("playstacja ");
lcd.setCursor(6,1);
lcd.print("3.0");

if(loginAnim == true){
 loginAnim = false;
 lcd.setCursor(5,3);
 lcd.print("wcisnij 1");

}else if(loginAnim == false){
 loginAnim = true;
 lcd.setCursor(5,3);
 lcd.print("         ");

}
p1 = digitalRead(8);
logowanie();
delay(100); 
logowanie();
delay(100);
logowanie();
delay(100); 
logowanie(); 
delay(100); 
logowanie();
delay(100);
logowanie();
delay(100);
logowanie();

}

// wczytywanie

lcd.clear();

lcd.setCursor(5,1); 
lcd.print("wczytywanie");

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

lcd.setCursor(17,1);
lcd.print(".");
delay(400);

lcd.setCursor(17,1);
lcd.print(" .");
delay(400);

lcd.setCursor(17,1);
lcd.print(" ."); delay(400);

lcd.setCursor(17,1);
lcd.print("   ");
}

lcd.clear();

//menu glowne:

menu:

while(menu == true){

if ((gry == false)&&(opcje == false)){

lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("1.gry");

lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("2.opcje");

p1 = digitalRead(8);
p2 = digitalRead(9);
p3 = digitalRead(10);

delay(1000);

if((p1 == HIGH)&&(p2 == LOW)&&(p3 == LOW)){

 gry = true;
 opcje = false;

}else if((p2 == HIGH)&&(p1 == LOW)&&(p3 == LOW)){

 opcje = true;
 gry = false;

}else if((p3 == HIGH)&&(p2 == LOW)&&(p1 == LOW)){
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("takiej opcji nie ma");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("w menu , wybierz");
 lcd.setCursor(0,2);
 lcd.print("1 albo 2!");

 delay(3500);
 lcd.clear();

}



if((gry == true)&&(opcje == false)){

 lcd.clear();

 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("1.nie nazwano");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("2.wyjdz");

 p1 = digitalRead(8);
 p2 = digitalRead(9);

 if((p1 == HIGH)&&(p2 == LOW)){



   lcd.clear();
   gra();
 }else if((p2 == HIGH)&&(p1 == LOW)){
   lcd.clear();
   goto menu;
 }


}



} 
}

}

void loop() {

}

void logowanie(){

if(p1 == HIGH){
login = true; 

}

}

void logowanieGra(){

   if(p1 == HIGH){
 loginGra = true;
}
}

void gra(){

delay(1000);

while(graMenu == true){

 lcd.setCursor(4,0);
lcd.print(",,test,,");

 if(graAnim == true){
   graAnim = false;
   lcd.setCursor(3,2);
   lcd.print("start");
 }else if(graAnim == false){
     graAnim = true;
   lcd.setCursor(3,2);
   lcd.print("     "); 
 }

 if(p1 == HIGH){
 goto dalszyCiagGry;
 graMenu = false;
 }

     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
     logowanieGra();
     delay(100);
} 

dalszyCiagGry: delay(10);

}
```

and tab "zmienne.h" (in Polish: variables .h)

```
int p1pin = 8;
 int p2pin = 9;
 int p3pin = 10;
 int p1 = 0;
 int p2 = 0; 
int p3 = 0;
 int buzzerpin = 6;

boolean login = false;
 boolean loginAnim = false;
 boolean menu = true;
 boolean gry = false;
 boolean opcje = false;
 boolean graAnim = false;
 boolean graMenu = true;
 boolean loginGra = false;
```

if someone was curious, this is my console project (more on instagram "Antek_Gzara_Animations") don't take into account the overall structure of the code, because I'm a beginner. and sorry for my english but i use google translate ;)

Comment: What about the simplest example provided with your <LiquidCrystal.h> library? Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

not

```
include <LiquidCrystal.h>
```

pre-processor directives are preceeded with a `#`!